# NestJS/TypeORM MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I've been trying to connect to a mongo container on docker with typeorm and nestjs and I've been getting this error :

```
Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/waelrabah/upwork_work/spoward/spoward-gql/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) TypeOrmModule
```

Mongo image code :

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --auth
    environment:
      # provide your credentials here
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=spoward
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=SpowardRoot
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=SpowardRootPass
      
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/db:/data/db
```

and this is the connection string : `mongodb://SpowardRoot:SpowardRootPass@mongo:27017/spoward`

Did someone ever encounter this issue before ?

Comment: Is your application running in the same Compose file, with the same `networks:` block?

Comment: Yes, the same compose file and `networks:` block

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this, apparently the host that I used `mongo` doesn't exist so on a linux distro you have to add it to `/etc/hosts` and associate to the ip address of your container, `docker inspect <container_id>` to get the ip address .
Tested it on Windows, it seems that you have to replace `mongo` with `localhost` and it should work. But you can also add the `mongo` host in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`